# cannot open steam after uprade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, steam

I have download and install steam successfully when using Ubuntu 13.04. Recently, I upgrade my system to 13.10, and I found that I cannot open steam anymore. The program just display nothing and then quit. Anyone have idea about how to install steam on Ubuntu 13.10 please?

Answer (score 1):

#### Try to re-install it

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

and then do a

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix some installation issues that may happen.

Comment: thanks, but im afraid that this does not work. still, I cannot open steam

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason there is a dependency that isn't installed when Steam is on 13.10. All I did to solve the problem was

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

And that was it. Hope it works for you!